# How to fetch multiple multiple data from multiple endpoints inside Promise.all?

Tags: reactjs, promise, get, fetch

I am trying to get multiple data from multiple fetch GET calls in Promise.all without having to write a .then and .catch for each Fetch.
This is the code I wrote and it is logging data still in prending promise. It seems like .json() doesn't work in this way.

```
Promise.all([
  fetch(allAirportsURL, bearer), 
  fetch(allFlightsURL, bearer)
  ])
  .then(([responseOne, responseTwo]) => {
    return [responseOne.json(), responseTwo.json()];
  })
  .then(([dataOne, dataTwo]) => {
    console.log('data', dataOne);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Yes, don't write a `.then()` on each fetch - write [one helper function to do that and also handle HTTP errors](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html), then call that twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try return `Promise.all([responseOne.json(), responseTwo.json()])` from first then caluse